# How to make named pipes in bash

Tags: bash, named-pipes

This program works great, but how do I go from supporting 2 files to supporting `n` files using the same [un]named pipe approach?

```
some_command \ 
    <(tar c --xattrs -C "$1" --pax-option="exthdr.name=%d/PaxHeaders/%f" . | xxd) \
    <(tar c --xattrs -C "$2" --pax-option="exthdr.name=%d/PaxHeaders/%f" . | xxd)
```

Comment: That syntax isn't limited to two pipes. What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: My input can consist of any number of arguments in $@; I'd like to pass them all to diff with similar pre-processing. I know how to do this only for a fixed number of arguments.

Comment: `diff` only takes two arguments at a time. What are you trying to do here exactly? Take pairs of inputs at a time?

Comment: Pretend diff can take many arguments at a time (I was mistaken on this, I see how it would be a confusing context)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using the process substitution syntax, create the named pipes explicitly. (Process substitution is a transient construct; you can't create them one at a time to save up for later use.)

```
declare -a pipes
for arg in "$@"; do
    new_pipe_name=pipe$((++i))
    pipes+=( "$new_pipe_name" )
    mkfifo "$new_pipe_name"
    tar c --xattrs -C "$arg" --pax-option="exthdr.name=%d/PaxHeaders/%f" . | 
      xxd > "$new_pipe_name" &
done

mycommand "${pipes[@]}"
rm "${pipes[@]}"
```